# Which version of Groovy is aligned with NextFlow releases?

Tags: groovy, nextflow

NextFlow documentation mentions compatible Java versions.  As well, I found a blog at nextflow.io that mentions use of Groovy 3.x in an earlier release.  However, nowhere have I found any documentation that makes clear what the alignment is between NextFlow version releases and Groovy.

Specifically, for NextFlow 22.x, which version of Groovy should I assume?

While a fairly minor point, this question does impact which body of documentation for Groovy that I reference.  I realize NextFlow docs should be sufficient; but for completeness, knowing the Groovy version as well would be helpful.

Comment: Running a NextFlow script shows the Groovy version:  `Runtime: Groovy 3.0.13 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.1+13` ... it could be helpful if that were in the online docs, too.

Comment: I would assume 3.0 and not worry too much about the sub-minor/revision number. It is now in maintenance anyway following the release of 4.0 early last year.